# neo4j Index cretion in a Mysql migration to neo4j

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

Regarding the creation of index for the nodes that we create I have a question..

If i make a migration from MySql to neo4j graph db do I have to create an index for every record or it's ok to create at the end ?

PS: Sorry for the dumb question I am new to it and I am trying to learn. here is the code: ` $query = 'SELECT * FROM product'; $result = mysql_query ($query);

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result) ) {
    $product = $this->client->makeNode ();
    $product->setProperty ('product_id',(int)$row[ 'product_id' ])
        ->setProperty ('sku', $row[ 'sku' ])
        ->save ();
    $productIndex =  new NodeIndex($this->client,'products');
    $productIndex->save();
    $productLabel = $this->client->makeLabel ('product');
    $product->addLabels (array ( $productLabel ));

    echo "Done creating " . $row[ 'product_id' ] . " node<br/>";

}`
```

also I am wondering how do I see i the index was created (in browser) or I cant see it only feel it? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the indexes in the browser with `:schema`

Not sure about your product index? I'm not familiar with the Neo4jPHP API. Are you sure that it is a new style schema index?

You can create the index or constraint also with plain cypher statements.

```
create index on :Product(product_id)
```

or

```
create constraint on (p:Product) assert p.product_id is unique
```

See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-schema-index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the index once

> $productIndex =  new NodeIndex($this->client,'products');
>       $productIndex->save();

Then add nodes to the index

> $productIndex>add($node, 'key', 'value');

check the example in neo4j github https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Indexes